# Android Kotlin RoomDB: Delete all data class inside entity with single query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Entity with 4 data class, I want to clear  the data in one data class without affecting other data class

```
@Entity(tableName = "DemoEntity")
data class ClassOne { ... }

data class ClassTwo { ... }

data class ClassThree { ... }

data class ClassFour { ... }
```

#To delete All

```
@Query("DELETE FROM DemoEntity")
fun deleteAll()
```

#How to delete all the data of ClassOne without deleting other data? There is some possibility to fetch all and delete it. but I want to delete in one query.

Comment: Your question is not vague enough, mate.

Comment: How can `DemoEntity` has 4 data classes in it . I am not sure i understand your database schema.  If there is only one Entity then there is only one table . Can u explain a bit about the schema you using in question .

Comment: All four data classes are written in a single file so I assumed four data classes are belong to DemoEntity because,  when I fire the query(@Query("DELETE FROM DemoEntity")) all the four data class values are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

As of `Room 1.1.0` you can use `clearAllTables()` which deletes all rows from all the tables that are registered to this database as entities()

**Note:** `clearAllTables()` is asynchronous and there is no way to tell when it completes

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is **where** clause in the SQLite query.

for example, you can use id to delete the rows or some other condition for example.

```
DELETE FROM DemoEntity
WHERE id = 2
ORDER BY type
LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset;
```

or something like this

```
DELETE FROM DemoEntity
WHERE name LIKE '%Santana%';
```

this is just example you can change this query according to your columns in the table and condition for deletion.